How can I display the Android video view on top of the game view?
I want to play a video in my .NET Android project. I have installed the MediaManager NuGet package version 1.2.2: https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager
But I only hear the sound of the video when I debug my project on my device. The problem is that the video view is under the game view and therefore I cannot see the video. If I don't create the game view then I can see the video when I debug my project on my device.
How can I display the video on top of the game view?
Activity1.cs:
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using MediaManager;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using SharedCode;

namespace TestPluginMedia
{

[Activity(

    Label = "@string/app_name",

    MainLauncher = true,

    Icon = "@drawable/icon",

    AlwaysRetainTaskState = true,

    LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance,

    ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.FullUser,

    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.Keyboard | ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize

)]

public class Activity1 : AndroidGameActivity
{

    private Game1 _game;

    private View _view;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        CrossMediaManager.Current.Init(this);

        CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaPlayer.ShowPlaybackControls = true;

        CrossMediaManager.Current.AutoPlay = true;

        var videoView = FindViewById<MediaManager.Platforms.Android.Video.VideoView>(Resource.Id.exoplayerview_activity_video);

        CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaPlayer.VideoView = videoView;

     

        _game = new Game1();

        _view = _game.Services.GetService(typeof(View)) as View;

        SetContentView(_view);

        _game.Run();

    }

}

}

Game1.cs:
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using MediaManager;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace SharedCode
{

public class Game1 : Game
{
    private GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics;
    private SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;
    

    public Game1()
    {
        _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);

        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        IsMouseVisible = true;

    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override async void LoadContent()
    {
        _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("https://video.mp4");

    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {             
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        base.Draw(gameTime);

    }

}

}

activity_main.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent">

<mediamanager.platforms.android.video.VideoView

    android:id="@+id/exoplayerview_activity_video"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="300dp"

    android:focusable="true"

    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>


Related: Placing/Overlapping(z-index) a view above another view in android However Android's View system isn't the best for active overlapping content as found in a game. If you are attempting a game see: Can you run XNA games on Android?
